# Using filter in pandas to get an exact match and partial match at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Y2000   Y2001   Y2002    Item    Item Code
34        43      65      12       Test
```

I want to extract the columns Y2000, Y2001, Y2002 and Item. I do not want to extract the 'Item Code' column. How do I do this without explicitly specifying column names, as I have tons of columns in the full dataframe? Right now, I am using the filter command but it is not working for me:

```
df.filter(like='Y|Item')
```

It just returns an empty dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC then you can use a regex pattern:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Y2000','Y2001','Y2002','Item','Item Code'])
df

Out[2]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Y2000, Y2001, Y2002, Item, Item Code]
Index: []

In [8]:
df.filter(regex='^Y\d{4}$|^Item$')

Out[8]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Y2000, Y2001, Y2002, Item]
Index: []
```

So `^Y\d{4}$|^Item$` looks for 'Y' at start followed by 4 digits and then terminates here with stop `$` 'Item' at start and stop `$` at end

Comment: thanks @EdChum, what does the r in regex = r'... do? Doesn't it convert something to a raw string? Why is that needed here?

Comment: it just denotes a raw string, it's just my personal convention, it'll work without it, it just interprets the string without needing to escape special characters but it's unnecessary here

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), you need the `regex` parameter:

```
df.filter(regex='Y|Item$')
```

where the columns satisfying `re.search(regex, col) == True` will be kept. The `like` version performs a sub-string search on the column names, which is why it does not work when a regex-like input such as `'Y|Item'` is supplied.